# How to sort multi-dimensional PHP array based on external array value priorities

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array in PHP that looks similar to:

```
$my_array_to_sort = [
    "data" => [
        [
            "name" => "orange",
            "id" => 23423,
        ],
        [
            "name" => "green",
            "id" => 34343,
        ],
        [
            "name" => "red",
            "id" => 65566,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I would like to re-sort this array based on name while keeping its structure and data using a sorting array that looks like this:

```
$priority = [
    "red" => 1,
    "orange" => 2,
    "green" => 3,
];
```

so that the final sort would result in

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => red
                    [id] => 65566
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => orange
                    [id] => 23423
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => green
                    [id] => 34343
                )
        )
)
```

Is uasort() the way to go here? Any code references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `uasort` as you are not trying to preserve keys in the array you are sorting. [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will suffice, passing the `$priority` array to the callback and sorting based on the priority of each entries name:

```
usort($my_array_to_sort['data'], function ($a, $b) use ($priority) {
    return $priority[$a['name']] - $priority[$b['name']];
});

print_r($my_array_to_sort);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => red
                    [id] => 65566
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => orange
                    [id] => 23423
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => green
                    [id] => 34343
                )
        )
)
```

To sort in reverse order, simply change the order of variables in the `return` expression:

```
usort($my_array_to_sort['data'], function ($a, $b) use ($priority) {
    return $priority[$b['name']] - $priority[$a['name']];
});
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kF34H)

Comment: This is great. Thank you. What if I need to sort the reverse order (highest priority value first ie, 3,2,1, etc.)

Comment: @yesinteractive just reverse the argument comparison, `return $priority[$b['name']] - $priority[$a['name']];` it will be sorted descending

Comment: @Kevin thanks for answering OPs comment. I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: Yes this answered the question. Tysm